# multiply two figures with typescript read NaN

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to get the total price after the value of the quantity is changed, but it reads NaN at the console

JS

```
getTotal(){
  this.totalPrice= (this.price) * (this.quantity) ;
  console.log(this.totalPrice)
}
```

HTML

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Price</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="price"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Quantity</ion-label>
  <ion-input (ionChange)="getTotal()" type="number"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Total</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="totalPrice"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a getter:
**HTML**

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Price</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="price"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Quantity</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="quanity" type="number"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Total</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="totalPrice"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

**Typescript:**

```
get totalPrice(){
  return (this.price) * (this.quantity) ;
}
```

Comment: i forgot to attach an ngModel to the quantity textbox

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `ngModel` directive in the `<ion-input>` for quantity. So, `this.quantity` never gets updated and I assume it's `undefined`. So in the end you're multiplying a number and `undefined` and

```
5 * undefined = NaN
```

Which is what you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

When quantity get change event you will call getTotal and use `this.quantity` to calculate it. However, this.quantity is not used in input as binding for the value.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Quantity</ion-label>
  <ion-input (ionChange)="getTotal()" type="number" [(ngModel)]="quantity"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```